# Why is my code returning a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, graph, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

I am trying to add a new vertex to my graph that will add it so that it is alphabetically ordered. However, I keep encountering segmentation fault. I tried using the debugger and valgrind, but it only tells me what method is causing the seg fault, my add_vertex.

```
    /* Adds a vertex with element new_vertex */
int add_vertex(Graph *graph, const char new_vertex[])
{
    Vertex *new, *curr = graph -> vertices, *prev;
    if ( has_vertex (*graph, new_vertex) || graph == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (prev = graph->vertices; curr = prev->next; prev = curr)
        if (curr->element > new_vertex)
            break;
    new = malloc ( sizeof ( Vertex ) );
    new->element = ( char *) malloc ( sizeof ( strlen ( new_vertex ) + 1) );
    strcpy ( new -> element, new_vertex );
    graph -> counter++;
    /* Adds a vertex to the graph */
    if (curr != NULL) {
        /* Case 1 or 2: Vertex not at end of the graph */
        if (prev != graph -> vertices) { /* Case 1: not at front */
            new -> next = curr;
            prev -> next = new;
        }
        else { /* case 2: at front */
            new -> next = curr;
            graph -> vertices -> next = new;
        }

    }
    else /* Case 3 or 4: at the end of the graph */
        if (prev != graph -> vertices){ /* Case 3: not at front */
            new -> next = NULL;
            prev -> next = new;
        }
        else{ /* Case 4: at front */
            new -> next = NULL;
            graph -> vertices -> next = new;
        }


    return 1;
}
```

Here is how I implemented my graph

```
#if !defined(GRAPH_IMPLEMENTATION_H) 
#define GRAPH_IMPLEMENTATION_H
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct edge
{   int cost;
    char* symbol;
} Edge;

typedef struct vertex
{   struct vertex *next;
    char* element;
    struct edge *connect;
    int counterE;
} Vertex;

typedef struct graph    
{   Vertex* vertices;
    int counter;
} Graph;
```

Comment: `if ( has_vertex (*graph, new_vertex) || graph == NULL)`? Think about what you've done.

Comment: Adding up to @EOF: The order of evaluation most likely is left to right.

Comment: Should braces be placed around the last `else`?

Comment: OT: Also in C there is no need to cast "*`malloc()` & Friends*", nor is it recommended in any ways. Be consistent.

Comment: @stackptr: Having put braces around the last "*else*" would have been nicer, indeed, but semantics are clear even without them, ... - at least for the compiler ;-)

Comment: @alk: Nothing "likely" about it. C11 draft standard, `6.5.14 Logical OR operator, Section 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;`

Answer (score 5):

a big mistake here

```
new -> element = ( char *) malloc ( sizeof ( strlen ( new_vertex ) + 1) );
//                                  ^^^^^
```

just do this:

```
new -> element =  malloc (  strlen ( new_vertex ) + 1 );
```